# How to Disable Auto Increment in EF Core For DB Seed?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I want to do some database seed when my database is being generated at this time I want to be able to set my own PK ID but after this I want to auto increment.

How can I do this?

If I try to set an id it will error out as auto increment is on.

```
var n = new Category(){
  id = 1
}

dbContext.Add(n);
dbContext.SaveChange();
```

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-identity-insert

Comment: hmm it is not workign for me I did this before SaveChanges()          dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Category ON");

Comment: @jmoerdyk - ok I got it to work but is there a easy way if I need to do mulitple ones in 1 saveChanges(for instance I got SubCategory what I want to set an Id as well)

Comment: As far as I know, you have to turn it on for each table individually, do your inserts and then turn it back off.

Comment: dang yea that was what I was finding